# How to get bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1 path in Azure function .Net project?

Tags: c#, .net, path, azure-functions, appsettings

When ever I build my project my appsettings.json file and hosts.json file go to /bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1 folder but my project dll and all other libraries goes to /bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1/bin folder. Now in my azure function I want the dynamically created path for my .json files. What I have tried is:

```
var appSettingsFileAbsPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath) + appSettingsFileName;
```

But again it gives me /bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1/bin path where my dll is present. Is there any function from which i can get /bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1 path where my json files comes when i build my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any function from which i can get /bin/debug/netcoreapp2.1
>   path where my json files comes

Your *Json* files would be located in `dllGrandParentpath`

```
      var dllPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
      var dllParentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dllPath);
      var dllGrandParentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dllParentPath); // This is Where your appsettings.json file and hosts.json file is present
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.